# A tensor product over a ring $R$ and over a domain $k$

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R=k[x,y]$, where $k$ is an integral domain, and let $\mathfrak m=xR+yR$. We can identify the $R$-module $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$ with $V$, where $V=k\bar x\oplus k\bar y$ is acted on trivially by $\mathfrak m$. My question is:

> Why $V\otimes _R V=V\otimes _k V$?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is why $$\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2\otimes_R\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2\simeq \mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2\otimes_{R/\mathfrak m} \mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2.$$ We have $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2\simeq \mathfrak m\otimes_RR/\mathfrak m$ and $R/\mathfrak m\otimes_RR/\mathfrak m\simeq R/\mathfrak m$. Now all should be clear.

Comment: I wrote the right side as: $(m\otimes _R R/m)\otimes _{R/m} (R/m\otimes _R m)$. But, since $R/m\otimes _{R/m} R/m\simeq R/m$ I could rewrite the former as $(m\otimes _R R/m)\otimes _R m $ which is isomorphic , as you mentioned, with $m\otimes_R(R/m\otimes_R R/m)\otimes _R m$. Is it what you mean?

Comment: @karparvar Not really, but I think this can be done as you did since $R/\mathfrak m\otimes_RR/\mathfrak m\simeq R/\mathfrak m$ is an isomorphism of $R$-modules, but in the same time an isomorphism of $R/m$-modules.